# Placing Random Characters on an Array Board in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random, character

I'm making a simple array board. I'm trying to make the character '$' appear 10 times in random places, and 'R' appear only once in random places. I've continued to change the randomization, but I know I'm approaching this the wrong way. The characters appear in random places *and* in random amounts.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am trying to maintain my nested `for` loop.

Edit: I placed my the last if statements I tried in the code instead of my placeholders.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class board
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char $;
        char R;
        char board[][] = new char[10][10];

        for(int x = 0; x < board.length; x++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
            {
                double random = Math.random();
                if(random >.01 && random <=.10)
                {
                    board[x][i] = 'R';
                }
                else if(random > .01 && random <= .15)
                {
                    board[x][i] = '$';
                }
                else {
                    board[x][i] = '.';
                }
                System.out.print(board[x][i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first two conditional statements are identical.

Comment: Your first two `if` conditions are identical and only the first one will ever evaluate.

Comment: That was a product of my frustration earlier. I screwed something up while trying fix things and ended up just leaving them both the same as place holders. None of the randomization I've tried has worked, however. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get random placing by iterating through all positions and comparing to a probability. What happens if too many are placed or not enough? A better algorithm is to generate random positions until you have enough on the board. Something like:

```
while (count < target) {
    int x = rand.getInt(size);
    int y = rand.getInt(size);
    if (board[x][y] == '.') {
        board[x][y] = '$';
        count++;
    }
}
```

That will automatically skip positions that have already been assigned the character and will continue until enough have been placed.

This can be made into a method that is used for both placements:

```
private void place(char toPlace, int target) {
    int count = 0;
    while (count < target) {
        int x = rand.getInt(size);
        int y = rand.getInt(size);
        if (board[x][y] == '.') {
            board[x][y] = toPlace;
            count++;
        }
    }
}

place('M', 1);
place('$', 10);
```

Comment: But am I able to preserve my nested `for` loop with this? I edited my post a little bit ago. I'm sorry, I'm very new, and I don't see how to incorporate this without losing that.

Comment: Are you certain you need to maintain the nested for loop?  If you do, the only way I can think of doing this would be to predetermine the positions where you are going to place each token (using a method similar to the one in this elegant solution) and then, when you loop through, use the predetermined positions to update your board.

Comment: I don't need it, per se, but for this code, I'm trying to keep the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that it places it randomly, but you have no code that controls how many are generated. You should have a counter for $ and a counter for R, and when you have enough, it shouldn't print that character anymore. Also, the current code can overwrite previously placed characters. You should probably add in an if-statement that checks the current value of the address that is about to be replaced, and make sure it's empty first.

Comment: Okay. I'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Remember to accept this answer if it helped you!